# C++ Builder Attaching Source

Tags: debugging, c++builder

I have a 3rd party lib file which I'm using to do translation. I have access to the source code and am curious if there is an easy way to connect that source code to my project, so that I can step through that code using a debugger and see where things are blowing up. E.g. Step through the Delphi code instead of seeing the assembly language code.

I've done a similar process with eclipse and java in the past, so I hope that there is an easy way to do this with C++ Builder.

Comment: Since the code base is in delphi/pascal, not in C++, I'm not sure if it will be possible to do what I want.

Comment: At least C++Builder can step through Delphi code when you step into functions of VCL components, so I guess attaching source shouldn't depend on whether the code is C++ or Delphi. Can't answer the question though.

Comment: Of course you can. You can include Delphi units on a C++ Builder project...

Comment: It might also depends on whether your .lib file has been compiled in debug mode or not.

Answer (score 0):

Under project options there is a "debug path" option.  Add whatever folder the source code is in to that path, and it should "just work".  If not, three things you can try, in this order:

1. Make sure you main app (EXE or DLL) is compiled in debug mode (i.e.-you can step through the code in your own app, right?)
2. Make sure the LIB is compiled in debug mode (I'm not sure this actually matters, but worth a check), since you have the source you should be able to rebuild if needed
3. Last resort.. since you have the source, you could just include the source in your own project (add all of the files) and not use the LIB at all.

All of this assumes you mean a static library, and not a LIB that just links to an external DLL (dynamic library).  If it is actually a DLL, then the DLL must be built in debug mode and usually has a separate file (TDS) with the debug info -- that file must be in the same location the DLL is loaded from.